# 2 nvarchar fields are not matching though the data is same?

Tags: sql-server

I want to join 2 tables using an `Inner Join` on 2 columns, both are of `(nvarchar, null)` type. The 2 columns have the same data in them, but the join condition is failing. I think it is due to the spaces contained in the column values.

I have tried `LTRIM`, `RTRIM` also

My query:

```
select 
    T1.Name1, T2.Name2
from 
    Table1 T1 
Inner Join 
    Table2 on T1.Name1 = T2.Name2
```

I have also tried like this:

```
on LTRIM(RTRIM(T1.Name1)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(T2.Name2))
```

My data:

```
Table1                  Table2
------                  ------
Name1(Column)           Name2(Column)           
-----                   ------              
Employee Data           Employee Data
Customer Data           Customer Data
```

When I check My data in 2 tables with

select T1.Name1,len(T1.Name1)as Length1,Datalength(T1.Name1)as DataLenght1 from Table1 T1

select T2.Name2,len(T2.Name2)as Length2,Datalength(T2.Name2)as DataLenght2 from Table2 T2

The result is different Length and DataLength Values for the 2 tables,They are not same for 2 tables.

I can't change the original data in the 2 tables. How can I fix this issue.

Thank You

Comment: Could you check the characterset? Maybe there are different encodings for the columns.

Comment: Yet one more example of why you don't use strings for relationships between tables.

Comment: There could be more between Employee and Data. Maybe some command characters like tab or carriage return. Just a short idea. Copy both values to an empty query window and check if there are some special chars between them.

Comment: @Sascha The fields are nvarchar(), that means Unicode.

Comment: Please can you give an example of two strings which do not match like you expect.

Comment: If you try `select '[' + Name1 + ']' from Table1` (and the same for your second table) - do you have spaces somewhere (possibly only in *one* of the two tables)?

Comment: Try to compare cast(Name1 as varbinary) and cast(Name2 as varbinary). Are they different?

Comment: They have to be different, otherwise they would match. The question is what is different. You can try the SELECT N'['+... thing and additionally you can try to check the length of both by using LEN(Name1), LEN(Name2).

Comment: can you tell me while joining what output you want

Comment: You could try to collate both sides to the same collation even though these should not differ if both tables are created in the same database and there does not really seem to be any difference in the values.

Answer (score 0):

Joins do not have special rules for equality. The equality operator always works the same way. So if a = b then the join on a = b would work. Therefore, a <> b.

Check the contents of those fields. They will not be the same although you think they are:

```
select convert(varbinary(max), myCol) from T
```

Unicode has invisible characters (that only ever seem to cause trouble).

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (name varchar(20))
insert into @t(name)values ('Employee Data'),('Customer Data')

declare @tt table (name varchar(20))
insert into @tt(name)values ('EmployeeData'),('CustomerData')

select t.name,tt.name from @t t 
INNER  JOIN @tt tt
ON RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(t.name,' ',''))) = RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(tt.name,' ','')))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the following schema

- Create a new table to store all the possible names
- Add needed keys and indexes
- Populate with existing names
- Add columns to your existing tables to store the index of the name
- Create relative foreign keys
- Populate the new columns with correct indexes
- Create procedure to perform an insert in new tables names only in case the value is not existing
- Perform the join using the new indexes